# fix layout with custom border-spacing

Tags: html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $ul=$("#task-list");
 var taskList=[
  {
   "name":"Test Task #1",
   "date":"12/01/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #2",
   "date":"12/02/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #3",
   "date":"12/03/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #4",
   "date":"12/04/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #5",
   "date":"12/05/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #6",
   "date":"12/06/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #7",
   "date":"12/07/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  }
 ];

 var stackTask=function (task){
  taskList.push(task);
 };

 var renderTask=function (task){
  var li='<li><span class="task-name"> '+task.name+ '</span> <span class="task-date">'+task.date+'</span> <span class="task-assigned">'+ task.assigned+'</span></li>';
  return li;
 }
 $.each(taskList, function(i, task) {
     $ul.append(renderTask(task));
 });


 $('#form-task').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var name=$("#txt_name");
  var date=$("#txt_date");
  var assignedTo=$("#txt_assigned_to");
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
   if ($(this).val()=='') {
    $(this).addClass('form-error');
   }else {
    $(this).removeClass('form-error');
   }
  });
  var task={
   "name":name.val(),
   "date":date.val(),
   "assigned":assignedTo.val()
  };
  if ($('.form-error').length==0) {
   stackTask(task);
   $ul.prepend(renderTask(task));
   name.val("");
   date.val("");
   assignedTo.val("");
  }
  
 });

});
```

```css
body{
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.container{
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size:28px;
 margin:0px;
}
.header h4 {
 color:#676767;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin:0px;

}
.header {
 display:block;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 10px solid #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom: none;
}

.content{
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; /*important for equal height columns*/
 width: 99%;
 overflow:auto;
 display: table; /* This is needed fo children elements using display table cell*/
 table-layout: fixed;
 padding-bottom: 50px; /*This needs to match footer height*/
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border-spacing: 5px;
 border-spacing-
}
.col1-content {
 padding-left: 10px;

}
.col1{

 background-color: #fff;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.col2 {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 display: table-cell; /*To make sibling columns equal in height*/
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content h4 {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
input[type="text"] { 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid #dedede;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color:#ececec;
  width:90%;
}
.form-error {
 border:1px solid red !important;
}

.form-row {
 display: block;
 padding:10px 0px;
}
.form-row label {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn {
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border:1px solid #000;
 padding:10px 15px;
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #434343;
 color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #303030;
}
#task-list{
 border:4px solid #dedede;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   list-style: none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
#task-list li {
 margin:0;
 padding:10px 20px;
}
#task-list li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ececec;
}
#task-list li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.task-name {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.task-date {
 color:#666666;
}
.task-assigned {
 float:right;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
   <h1>Task Tracker</h1>
   <h4>v2.0</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="col1">
    <div class="col1-content">
     <h4>Create a Task</h4>
     <form method="post" action="" id="form-task">
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_name">Task Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_date">Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_date" id="txt_date">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_assigned_to" id="txt_assigned_to">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h4>Existing Tasks</h4>
    <ul id="task-list"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

border-spacing set to the .content div causes the header border not to touch the .content div.

My output should look like this:
[image]

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing` should be able to take 2 values (horizontal/vertical)

```
border-spacing:  5px 0;
```

test snippet below to check it out

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $ul=$("#task-list");
 var taskList=[
  {
   "name":"Test Task #1",
   "date":"12/01/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #2",
   "date":"12/02/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #3",
   "date":"12/03/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #4",
   "date":"12/04/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #5",
   "date":"12/05/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #6",
   "date":"12/06/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  },
  {
   "name":"Test Task #7",
   "date":"12/07/2012",
   "assigned":"John Doe"
  }
 ];

 var stackTask=function (task){
  taskList.push(task);
 };

 var renderTask=function (task){
  var li='<li><span class="task-name"> '+task.name+ '</span> <span class="task-date">'+task.date+'</span> <span class="task-assigned">'+ task.assigned+'</span></li>';
  return li;
 }
 $.each(taskList, function(i, task) {
     $ul.append(renderTask(task));
 });


 $('#form-task').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var name=$("#txt_name");
  var date=$("#txt_date");
  var assignedTo=$("#txt_assigned_to");
  $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function() {
   if ($(this).val()=='') {
    $(this).addClass('form-error');
   }else {
    $(this).removeClass('form-error');
   }
  });
  var task={
   "name":name.val(),
   "date":date.val(),
   "assigned":assignedTo.val()
  };
  if ($('.form-error').length==0) {
   stackTask(task);
   $ul.prepend(renderTask(task));
   name.val("");
   date.val("");
   assignedTo.val("");
  }
  
 });

});
```

```css
body{
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.container{
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size:28px;
 margin:0px;
}
.header h4 {
 color:#676767;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin:0px;

}
.header {
 display:block;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 10px solid #e2e2e2;
 border-bottom: none;
}

.content{
 position: relative;
 height: 100%; /*important for equal height columns*/
 width: 99%;
 overflow:auto;
 display: table; /* This is needed fo children elements using display table cell*/
 table-layout: fixed;
 padding-bottom: 50px; /*This needs to match footer height*/
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: 10px;
 border-spacing:  5px 0;
}
.col1-content {
 padding-left: 10px;

}
.col1{

 background-color: #fff;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 display: table-cell;
}
.col2 {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 10px;
 display: table-cell; /*To make sibling columns equal in height*/
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

.content h4 {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 16px;
}
input[type="text"] { 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px solid #dedede;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color:#ececec;
  width:90%;
}
.form-error {
 border:1px solid red !important;
}

.form-row {
 display: block;
 padding:10px 0px;
}
.form-row label {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn {
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border:1px solid #000;
 padding:10px 15px;
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #434343;
 color: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #303030;
}
#task-list{
 border:4px solid #dedede;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   list-style: none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
#task-list li {
 margin:0;
 padding:10px 20px;
}
#task-list li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ececec;
}
#task-list li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.task-name {
 font-family: Georgia, serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.task-date {
 color:#666666;
}
.task-assigned {
 float:right;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
   <h1>Task Tracker</h1>
   <h4>v2.0</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="col1">
    <div class="col1-content">
     <h4>Create a Task</h4>
     <form method="post" action="" id="form-task">
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_name">Task Name</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_name" id="txt_name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_date">Date</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_date" id="txt_date">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <label for="txt_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>
       <input type="text" name="txt_assigned_to" id="txt_assigned_to">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Submit">
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
    <h4>Existing Tasks</h4>
    <ul id="task-list"></ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```